# Display 0 when join is not successful

Tags: sql-server, join

I am using SQL Server to solve the following problem.

I have 3 tables T1, T2, T3

**T1**:

```
ID    Name    Country
----------------------
 1     PR      IN
 2     AR      US
```

**T2**:

```
 ID     AGE
------------
 1      32
 2      36
 3      40
```

**T3**:

```
 ID     T1_ID    T2_ID   Amount
--------------------------------
 1       1         1       100
 2       1         2       300
```

Required output

```
T1.Name     T2.Age     T3.Amount
---------------------------------
 PR            32        100
 PR            36        200
 PR            40         0
```

My query is :

```
select 
    T1.name, T2.Age, T3.amount 
from 
    T3 
join 
    T1 on T1.id = T3.T1_ID --fixed a typo here
right join 
    T2 on T2.id =  T3.T2_ID
where 
    T1.id = 1
```

My current output is:

```
    T1.Name     T2.Age     T3.Amount
    --------------------------------
      PR         32        100
      PR         36        200
```

I would really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Your `where` clause doesn't allow for NULLs so the join becomes `inner` rather than `right`.

Comment: Even when I remove the where clause I am not able to get the desired output

Comment: Are you sure this is your required output ? looking at the data you have shown it is not ideally possible as for the 3rd row I don't think you will have name as PR as PR has ID of 1 .  Also, it should be only age being populated I assume amount and name should be nulls if you want 3rd row

Comment: Even if it has null for name and amount and only age is displayed I am ok with it. Could you please help me with the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the **FROM** statement on T2 and T1 because you want all records for T2 and T1 as a Cartesian product, limited by WHERE

instead of joining T3 in the **FROM**, using a *subselect* for T3 allows you to use **ISNULL**:

```
SELECT T1.NAME, 
       T2.age, 
       ISNULL((SELECT amount 
               FROM   T3 
               WHERE  T1.id = T3.T1_id 
                      AND T2.id = T3.T2_id), 0) AS Amount 
FROM   T2 CROSS JOIN 
       T1
WHERE  T1.id = 1
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. If you in fact want a Cartesian product on purpose, use `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: thanks, marc_s, it is indeed better to be more explicit and not use a comma